# Why do my shaders render differently in the simulator?

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-ui, unity-shader-graph

I am using simple shaders on the cards in my game. The shader is assigned as a material to a white image the covers the whole card.

They render as intended in the scene view, but do not in IOS simulator. In the simulator the overlaid image has no transparency, with transparency represented by black instead. The shader is also responsive to view angle, however the simulator version does not render over the entire card. Weirdly, the simulator version initially shows the full shader, but shows less and less as it is rotated.

Remember the left image is the intended appearance. Thanks for any help!!

[image]

Comment: Can you share the steps to create a shader that exhibits this problem? Once readers can reproduce the issue, they can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: Seems like Z fighting.